# How to generate in app notification in android app?

Tags: android, android-push-notification

I want to generate in app notification for my app like if boss update something bell icon will change, but nothing show on notification bar of Android app and when the user click bell icon it again take to new activity which shows what is the notification. What is the way to use this and how the icon will change before and after reading notification.

Comment: What have you tried? @GunjanBansal  show some code.

Comment: I tried to find some sample code but i was not able to find any code according to my requirement i am new in android so need some help.

Comment: Try this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm

Comment: thanks i saw this but i don't want this kind of notification i want notification like you tube show you when you open app and is show on subscription icon if somebody likes your video or comment on something if you disable push notification also.

Comment: Have you triggered any function when you want a notification?

Comment: i have tried with push notification tutorial but the issue is i cannot use firebase i have to use only php and mysql is there anyway??

Comment: use background services